# Prove by induction. Let $n$ be a square number $>= 9$. Prove that $n - 1$ is a composite number.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

How to prove that using induction?

My solution using strong induction:

Base case: $n = 9$

$9 - 1 = 8$, we can get $8$ by multiplying $2 * 4$. Therefore our base case is true.

Induction hypothesis: let's assume that $i$ is composite, $1 <= i < k$, $k \geq 9$.

$P(i) = i - 1$ means that $i - 1$ is a composite number (assuming)

$P(i) = i - 1 = p * q, 1 \leq p < (i-1), 1 \leq q < (i-1)$

Induction step:

$P(k) = k -1$

Using our induction hypothesis we know that (assuming that it is true) all values in this range $9 <= i < k$ is composite, since $k-1$ is in this range, therefore $k-1$ is composite.

Is it correct? Should I use weak induction instead?

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine

Comment: I can't follow your argument.  Where does "square number" appear in your solution?  What does $P(i)$ signify?  In any case, the claim is easier to prove without induction.  Just consider the expression $m^2-1$.

Comment: Note, it's not true that we can always write $m^2-1$ as $p\times q$ with both $p,q≥9$. With $m=4$, we have $15=3\times 5$.  So the inequalities you wrote do not generally hold.

Comment: moreover, $p$ and $q$ shouldn't be one.. one of them being 1 yeilds a prime

Comment: @lulu It is the integer $m^2$ which is greater than 9, not the factors of $m^2-1$.

Comment: @Carnby  No...The OP write $i-1=p\times q$ with both $p,q≥9$.  Though, to be sure, I have no idea what $i$ is supposed to be.  I am guessing that $i$ is meant to be $m^2$, though the OP never mentions squares in the proof...it appears that the OP believes that *all* natural numbers greater than $9$ are composite.

Comment: @lulu OK, then I think I read an edited version of the question in which he had already amended that.  Sorry then :)

Comment: I think that $k^2-1$ is composite for $k\ge 3$ should be shown by considering the proper factors $k-1$ and $k+1$ instead of applying induction.

Answer (score 4):

The simple way to prove this statement is just: Let $n \ge 9$ be some perfect square; say $n = s^2$. Then $n-1 = (s+1)(s-1)$, which shows $n-1$ is composite as long as $s-1 > 1$. In fact we have $n \ge 9$ and thus $s = \sqrt n \ge \sqrt 9 = 3$, so $s-1 \ge 2$, so we're done.

I don't think induction is a great strategy here. Is there some external reason you're forced to try to use that technique? For example if I need to show $14^2 - 1 = 195$ is not prime, then I don't really see how it helps to know that $13^2 - 1 = 168$ is not prime. Anyway an induction proof would almost certainly be more work than the above.

---

You're making a couple of mistakes in your attempted induction proof.

1. You're supposed to be proving that "perfect square - 1" is composite, but you're setting up as if you will prove that all integers $\ge 9$ are composite. That claim is false so you're doomed before you start!
2. Your induction hypothesis tells you that the claim holds for $k-1$, which says that all numbers from 9 up to $\color{red}{k-2}$ are composite. You need to prove the claim for $k$, which would mean that all numbers from 9 up to $\color{red}{k-1}$ are composite. So your simple proof won't work because you haven't shown that $k-1$ is composite in this situation. In fact, it will be impossible to prove that! The induction step is just not true in general, because of the mistake you made in setting up your induction as mentioned above.

Comment: It's a college assignment, so I'm only allowed to use induction. But your way to solve is pretty good and straightforward.

Comment: @H3il Added explanation of what went wrong in your attempted proof; hope that can help your understanding. I really don't see a way to use induction *well* here, but you can always set up the induction hypothesis using the statement P(k) = "k^2-1 is composite" and then just prove the induction step without actually relying on the induction hypothesis...

Comment: awesome! I finally get it!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want an induction proof, then here's how:
Base case: If $n = 9$, then $3^2-1 = 8$ which is composite.
Lets assume if $n = k^2$ then $k^2-1$ is a composite number.
So we need to prove this for next $k$, or $k' = k+1  $
$n' = (k+1)^2 $
So we need to prove $(k+1)^2-1$ is composite.
So $(k+1-1)(k+1+1) = k(k+2)  $
now here $k>=3$, So $k(k+2)$ has to be composite as $k ≠ 1$.

Comment: But, what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: @H3il David Clyde has underlined the mistakes, in your method in his answer. Could you go through it and let me know if you have any issues?

Comment: @H3il, this is what I meant above when I said you could "prove it by induction" by just never using the induction hypothesis. (Please never do this in real life! But maybe it's the best you can do in the weird restricted setting of this homework assignment.) Thanks mrtechtroid for typing it out.

Comment: @mrtechtroid thanks! I finally get it!